# Selecting rows from DataTable by DateTime column (hours)

Tags: c#, .net

```
DatarowsForOneDay = dt.Select(
    dt.Columns[0].Caption + "='" + x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH") + "'");
```

doesn't work, but

```
DatarowsForOneDay = dt.Select(
    dt.Columns[0].Caption + "='" + x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "'");
```

works.

So how can I select the date with a same hour?

Variable `x` type is `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING or LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

or

```
dt.Columns[0].Caption + " LIKE '" + x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH") + "*'"
```

Comment: Невозможно выполнить операцию "Like" над System.DateTime и System.String. в System.Data.BinaryNode.SetTypeMismatchError(Int32 op, Type left, Type right)

Comment: да елки палки ;) 

1) Don't use Caption (look for Value or something else)

2) 
x1 = new DateTime(x.day, x.month, x.year, x.hour, 0, 0);
x2 = x1.AddHours(1);
use .Caption >= x1 and .Caption < x2

Comment: some small mistake, use so (year first): new DateTime(x.YEAR, x.month, x.day, x.hour, 0, 0)

Comment: dt.Select("'"+dt.Columns[0].Caption + "' = '" + x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH") + "'"); That was so foolish from me >_<

Answer (score 2):

The `.Select` method accepts a filter expression with the same syntax of the one used in `DataColum.Expression`. You can check MSDN entry for detailed information:

[DataColumn.Expression Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

If LINQ is available you can do something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("DT", typeof(DateTime));

foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new DateTime(2010, 3, 10, item, 20, 10));
}

DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(dr => 
    ((DateTime)dr["DT"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH") == "2010-03-10 10")
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(rows.Length);
```

Comment: How to convert rows ot DataRows[] ?

Comment: @nCdy, you would use the `ToArray` extension method. I updated the example to use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code. Iterate all rows in `DataTable` and add into `searchRecords` List according to same date and hour.

```
List<DataRow> searchRecords = new List<DataRow>();
string searchDateOnHour = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH");
foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows)
{
    DateTime recordDate;
    DateTime.TryParse(item["comDate"].ToString(), out recordDate);
    string recordDateHour = recordDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH");        
    if (searchDateOnHour == recordDateHour)
        searchRecords.Add(item);            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm